# Cannon Matrix Multiplication With MPI, Dead-Lock

Tags: c++, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to implement Cannon Matrix Multiplication Algorithm With Windows MPI in C++14. I am using http://boron.physics.metu.edu.tr/ozdogan/GraduateParallelComputing.old/ceng505/node133.html for the reference but I could not achive running the algorithm.

I am creating a 4x4 Cartesian Topology. Then executing a shift operation on the matrices that the amount of the shift is decided by the row number.

Only the processes on the first row seems passing this line **"MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -mycoords[0], &shiftsource, &shiftdest);"** and the rest is waiting (dead-lock).

When I change the line as **"MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -1, &shiftsource, &shiftdest);"** (which shifts only 1 time instead of using the row index) all processes are passing the line (no dead-lock).

I am compiling the code on Visual Studio 22 and running the executable with:
**mpiexec -np 16 HW1.exe**

Here is how my code looks like:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

void MatrixMatrixMultiply(int n, double* a, double* b, double* c, MPI_Comm comm)
{
  int i;
  int nlocal;
  int npes, dims[2], periods[2];
  int myrank, my2drank, mycoords[2];
    int uprank, downrank, leftrank, rightrank;
  int shiftsource, shiftdest;
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Comm comm_2d;

  /* Get the communicator related information */
  MPI_Comm_size(comm, &npes);
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &myrank);

  /* Set up the Cartesian topology */
  dims[0] = dims[1] = std::sqrt(npes);

  /* Set the periods for wraparound connections */
  periods[0] = periods[1] = 1;

  /* Create the Cartesian topology, with rank reordering */
  MPI_Cart_create(comm, 2, dims, periods, 1, &comm_2d);

  /* Get the rank and coordinates with respect to the new topology */
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm_2d, &my2drank);
  MPI_Cart_coords(comm_2d, my2drank, 2, mycoords);

  /* Compute ranks of the up and left shifts */
  MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -1, &rightrank, &leftrank);
  MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 1, -1, &downrank, &uprank);

  /* Determine the dimension of the local matrix block */
  nlocal = n / dims[0];

  /* Perform the initial matrix alignment. First for A and then for B */
  MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -mycoords[0], &shiftsource, &shiftdest);
  // When I comment the line above and open the line below, all processes are passing here
    //MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -1, &shiftsource, &shiftdest);

  MPI_Sendrecv_replace(a, nlocal * nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm_2d, &status);

    fprintf(stdout, "rank: %d\n", myrank);
    fflush(stdout);

  MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 1, -mycoords[1], &shiftsource, &shiftdest);
  MPI_Sendrecv_replace(b, nlocal * nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm_2d, &status);

  /* Get into the main computation loop */
  for (i = 0; i < dims[0]; i++)
    {
        c[0] += a[0] + b[0];

    /* Shift matrix a left by one */
    MPI_Sendrecv_replace(a, nlocal * nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, leftrank, 1, rightrank, 1, comm_2d, &status);

    /* Shift matrix b up by one */
    MPI_Sendrecv_replace(b, nlocal * nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, uprank, 1, downrank, 1, comm_2d, &status);
    }

  /* Restore the original distribution of a and b */
  MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, +mycoords[0], &shiftsource, &shiftdest);
  MPI_Sendrecv_replace(a, nlocal * nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm_2d, &status);

  MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 1, +mycoords[1], &shiftsource, &shiftdest);
  MPI_Sendrecv_replace(b, nlocal * nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm_2d, &status);

  MPI_Comm_free(&comm_2d); /* Free up communicator */
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    double a[16] =
    {
        2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0,
        9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0,
        5.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0,
        8.0, 7.0, 3.0, 4.0
    };
    double b[16] = {
        3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 6.0,
        2.0, 7.0, 6.0, 3.0,
        7.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0,
        4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0
    };
    double c[16] = {
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
    };
    
    // Transpose
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            double t = a[i * 4 + j];
            a[i*4+j] = a[j*4+i];
            a[j * 4 + i] = t;

            t = b[i * 4 + j];
            b[i*4+j] = b[j*4+i];
            b[j * 4 + i] = t;

            t = c[i * 4 + j];
            c[i*4+j] = c[j*4+i];
            c[j * 4 + i] = t;
        }
    }

    MatrixMatrixMultiply(4, a, b, c, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        // print SUCCESS if the output matrix is correct
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        {
            printf("%f ", c[i]);
            if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't think the site is wrong, and I can not figure out where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm... I got a SIGILL, Illegal instruction. `#0  0x00007ffff57f718e in psm3_context_set_affinity (ep=0x58cc40, nic_cpuset=...) at prov/psm3/psm3/psm_context.c:730` already att the `MPI_Init`.

Comment: I am using Windows Version(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/microsoft-mpi) of MPI on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 22. Maybe there is difference between what you are using?

Comment: Most probably. I'm on Fedora 38. It seems like the MPI library is trying to download something and that it fails because valgrind shows `Syscall param socketcall.getsockopt(optlen) points to uninitialised byte(s)` and `getsockopt_syscall (getsockopt.c:29)`. Can't be good :-)

Comment: MPI uses sockets to create a network afaIk. Might that be the reason?

Comment: Could be. I've never used it myself but I _have_ compiled and executed MPI programs on my Fedora before. That was before I upgraded to Fedora 38 though. Could be the reason.

Comment: @TedLyngmo A library can not download anything. The problems with your installation have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @Stuart The sockets have nothing to do with it. If you're running on a single 16 core machine there are not even any sockets create: the library optimizes the "network" calls to become straight memory copies.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout _"A library can not download anything"_ - of course they can. I have even written a library that does, so you need to check your sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Cannon's algorithm you want to have a ringwise shift, so each process should shift by 1 in some direction. Your line:

```
MPI_Cart_shift(comm_2d, 0, -mycoords[0]
```

means that each process shifts by an amount that depends on the process. This is not a ring, and it's entirely predictable that you get deadlock. Most likely there will be two processes doing a `Sendrecv` to the same target, and that target may not be doing any receive from them.

Comment: I did not understand how each process shifts by an amount depends on the process. mycoord[0] holds the row index of the process in the Cartesian, does it not?

Comment: Oh, I see how they collapse. Thanks!